# C cache performance exercise

Tags: c

I was doing an exercise regarding cache performance by measuring cache misses. The performance will be tested against an exercise of creating a linked list and selecting values from the list.  The exercise is the following:

**implement a linked list that will contain elements of the type**

```
typedef struct node {
   int size;
   int *val;
   struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

val variable is pointing to an array containing « size » elements.

*Now fill your link list with 1 000 000 array of size 100.*

1. *First we will select 500 000 values (i,j ) for i=0 to 499 and j= 0 to 99*
2. *Now we select randomly 500 000 values i and j in the link list and retrieve them.*
3. *Now fill your link list with 2 000 000 array of size randomly chosen between 1
   and 200 and select 500 000 contiguous or random values.*

I implemented the following code and also added the possibility to get from terminal which exercise to run (0 -> normal select, 1 -> random select, 2 -> contiguous and 3 for all).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


struct node {
    int size;
    int* val;
    struct node* next;
};

clock_t start, end;
double cpuTimeUsed;


//initialize head in NULL for empty linked list
struct node* head;

//push new node at beginning
void push(int* val, int size) {
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->size = size;

    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

//does not check if head is null
//assumes i and j are positive integers >= 0

int retrieve(int i, int j) {
    int indexNode = 0;
    int indexElement = 0;
    struct node* current = head;
    while (indexNode < i) {
        current = current->next;
        indexNode++;
    }

    int size = current->size;
    int* values = current->val;

    while (indexElement < j && indexElement < size) {
        indexElement++;
        values++;
    }
    return *values;
}

void deleteList() {
    struct node* current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        struct node* next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    head = NULL;
}

struct node* getNode(int index) {
    struct node* current = head;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
}

void initialize(int numberNodes, int numberVals) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++) {
        int array[numberVals];
        int* values = array;
        push(values, numberVals);
    }
}

void initializeRandomSize(int numberNodes, int maxValues) {
    int i;
    int randomSize;
    for (i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++) {
        randomSize = (rand() % 200) + 1; //return a number between 1 and 200
        int array[randomSize];
        int* values = array;
        push(values, randomSize);

    }

}

void performNormalSelect() {
    //selecting 500,000 values from 0 to 499 in i and j in 0 to 99
    int value;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            value = retrieve(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void performRandomSelect(int numberNodes, int numberVals) {
    //randomly select 500,000 values
    int i;
    int j;
    int n;
    int value;
    for (n = 0; n < 500000; n++) {
        i = rand() % numberNodes;
        j = rand() % numberVals;
        value = retrieve(i, j);
    }
}

void performContiguousSelect(int numberNodes) {
        int valuesSelected = 0;
        int nodeNumber;
        int i;
        int value;
        struct node* currentNode;

        while (valuesSelected < 500000) {
            //get a random node 
            int nodeNumber = rand() % numberNodes;
            currentNode = getNode(nodeNumber);
            int size = currentNode->size;
            //get all values in nodes val
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                value = retrieve(nodeNumber, i);
                valuesSelected++;
            }
        }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL)); //used for random numbers

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Oops, only accept a value for option number\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char option = argv[1][0];

    switch (option) {
        case '0' :
            initialize(1000000, 100);
            //select values from i in range(0, 499) and j in range(0,99)
            start = clock();
            performNormalSelect();
            end = clock();
            cpuTimeUsed = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Time for normal select: %f\n", cpuTimeUsed);
            break;

        case '1' :
            initialize(1000000, 100);
            //select randomly values
            start = clock();
            performRandomSelect(1000000, 100);
            end = clock();
            cpuTimeUsed = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Time for random select: %f\n", cpuTimeUsed);
            break;

        case '2':
            //fill list with 2000000 of random size 1 and 200 and select 500000 continuos
            initializeRandomSize(2000000, 200);
            start = clock();
            performContiguousSelect(2000000);
            end = clock();
            cpuTimeUsed = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Time for contiguous select: %f\n", cpuTimeUsed);
            break;

        case '3':
            //perform all of the above
            initialize(1000000, 100);
            start = clock();
            performNormalSelect();
            end = clock();
            double cpuNormal = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            start = clock();
            performRandomSelect(1000000, 100);
            end = clock();
            double cpuRandom = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            deleteList();
            initializeRandomSize(2000000, 200);
             start = clock();
            performContiguousSelect(2000000);
            end = clock();
            double cpuCont = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            printf("Time normal select: %f\n", cpuNormal);
            printf("Time random select: %f\n", cpuRandom);
            printf("Time contiguous select: %f\n", cpuCont);
            break;

        default :
            cpuTimeUsed = 0;
            printf("Time: %f\n", cpuTimeUsed);
    }







    return 0;
}
```

I then use valgrind in order to check the cache misses

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --simulate-cache=yes ./program program-arguments
```

The issue arises when I try to run the profiler with the random select. The profiler takes more than 8 hours and didn't finish even then. I know the random selection does give a result as I tried the program without the use of the profiler. 

I am running the program on a Ubuntu VM with the following configuration:

- OS: 18.04
- Number of processors: 2
- Base memory: 4096 MB
- Initial hard disk memory 10GB

Is it a problem with the code, or should I let the profiler run for more time? Any feedback is appreciated, thank you!

(edit)
There is also an optimization question but I am having trouble trying to understand how to implement it to the previous code.

Optimisation- Now we will try to optimise this link list. For this purpose we will
allocate a large memory space of 100 000 000 bytes and replace the pointer by
indices in this large memory space. This mean that the node struct is now

```
typedef struct node {
int size;
int val;
struct node nextInd;
} node_t;
```

Where val is now an index in the memory we have allocated and next node is
identified by an index.

Comment: Why don't you try to run the program with smaller numbers (instead of 2000000, 1000000, 500000, etc) and see if it still hangs?

Comment: `int array[numberVals];
        int* values = array;
        push(values, numberVals);` is invalid - the pointer to `array` stop existing on the end of the `}`. All `newNode->val = val;` pointers are invalid. You have to use malloc.

Answer (score 1):

This allocates the `array` on the stack, uses the pointers to initialize your structures and after that `array` is gone, and all your pointers become invalid:

```
int array[numberVals];
int* values = array;
```

So when you use these invalid pointers and try to increment them in `retrieve`, it's not going to end well.